# Attach event on pseudo-element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to attach a click element only on the :after pseudo-element on the following fiddle:

```
<div class="tag deletable", style="style")>
  Tagname
</div>

.tag {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  line-height: 1em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-right: 5px solid;
 }

 .deletable {
  border-right: 18px solid;
  position: relative;
}

.deletable:after {
  content: "\D7";
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  right: -12px;
  top: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x2ztqdbm/

But it seems that is not possible. Is there a way to achieve that?
If not, can someone help me rewriting the HTML code in order to not use a pseudo-element? It's important that the :after section never breaks to the next line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want to achieve. What exactly should the pseudo-element do?

Comment: by "attach event" you mean the `click` event in JS? You can do it like this https://jsfiddle.net/x2ztqdbm/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

HTML

```
<div class="tag deletable", style="style")>
  Tagname
  <span class="wrong">x</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tag {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  line-height: 1em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-right: 5px solid;
 }

 .deletable {
  border-right: 18px solid;
  position: relative;
}

.wrong {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  right: -12px;
  top: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Preety much the same. use a font-awesome icon in place of 'x'

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/x2ztqdbm/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo elements (as far as I know) are not part of the DOM, so you can't attach events to them. However, why not using an inline element like a  tag or something like that? It would be even easier...

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a click event to a pseudo element using the `pointer-events` css-rule, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/cq9yzjeb/